# react native maps not working with expo Bare app

Tags: android, react-native, expo, react-native-maps, react-native-linking

I was using expo 34 managed workflow, for some extra features I need to eject my expo app.when I ejected expo app except `react-native-maps` everything is working fine.

I have followed the [react-native-maps](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-maps/blob/HEAD/docs/installation.md) each and every step for linking. when i run `yarn android` **build finished successfully**(not showing me any error in the android studio also) but **my app getting crash when it going to open**. If I commented that native code (react-native-maps config) app is working fine.

here is my code.

**android/settings.gradle**

```
include ':react-native-gesture-handler'
project(':react-native-gesture-handler').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/android')
include ':react-native-maps'
project(':react-native-maps').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-maps/lib/android')
includeUnimodulesProjects()
```

**android/app/build.gradle**

```
dependencies {
    implementation project(':react-native-screens')
    implementation project(':react-native-reanimated')
    implementation project(':react-native-gesture-handler')
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
    implementation(project(':react-native-maps')){
       exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-base'
       exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-maps'
   }
   implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:10.0.1'
   implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.0.1'
    addUnimodulesDependencies()
}
```

**android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="my_api_key"/>
```

**MainApplication.java**

```
import com.airbnb.android.react.maps.MapsPackage;

@Override
    protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
      return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
          new MainReactPackage(),
          new ReanimatedPackage(),
          new RNGestureHandlerPackage(),
          new RNScreensPackage(),
          new ModuleRegistryAdapter(mModuleRegistryProvider),
          new MapsPackage()
      );
    }
```

**logcat** warnings

```
2019-10-01 13:23:33.638 18391-18391/? E/:accountservic: Not starting debugger since process cannot load the jdwp agent.
2019-10-01 13:23:33.661 18352-18352/? E/ctivate.servic: Invalid ID 0x00000000.
2019-10-01 13:23:33.680 18352-18352/? E/ctivate.servic: Invalid ID 0x00000000.
2019-10-01 13:23:33.742 18391-18391/? E/:accountservic: Invalid ID 0x00000000.
2019-10-01 13:23:33.767 18391-18391/? E/:accountservic: Invalid ID 0x00000000.
2019-10-01 13:23:33.784 18391-18391/? E/:accountservic: Invalid ID 0x00000000.
2019-10-01 13:23:33.808 18391-18391/? E/:accountservic: Invalid ID 0x00000000.
2019-10-01 13:23:33.906 18447-18447/? E/facebook.katan: Not starting debugger since process cannot load the jdwp agent.
2019-10-01 13:23:33.937 18276-18276/com.mapview E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.mapview, PID: 18276
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mapview/com.mapview.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2946)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3081)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1831)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6809)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:876)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:555)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:518)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:457)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:145)
        at com.facebook.react.ReactActivityDelegate.loadApp(ReactActivityDelegate.java:89)
        at com.facebook.react.ReactActivityDelegate.onCreate(ReactActivityDelegate.java:75)
        at com.facebook.react.ReactActivity.onCreate(ReactActivity.java:52)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7224)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7213)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1272)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2926)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3081) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1831) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6809) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:876) 
2019-10-01 13:23:33.941 569-569/? E/SELinux: avc:  denied  { find } for service=miui.mqsas.MQSService pid=18276 uid=10245 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app_27:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:mqs_service:s0 tclass=service_manager permissive=0
2019-10-01 13:23:33.942 18276-18276/com.mapview E/MQSEventManagerDelegate: failed to get MQSService.
2019-10-01 13:23:34.003 1705-1717/? E/ActivityTrigger: activityResumeTrigger: not whiteListedcom.mi.android.globallauncher/com.miui.home.launcher.Launcher/2070005
2019-10-01 13:23:34.110 701-13206/? E/QSEECOMAPI: Error::Cannot de-alloc memory. priv handle is NULL!!.
2019-10-01 13:23:34.317 18447-18447/? E/ACRA: Initializing ANR detector for process: com.facebook.katana
2019-10-01 13:23:34.328 18447-18447/? E/FacebookApplication: Unable to install asan reader
2019-10-01 13:23:34.382 18447-18447/? E/dalvik-internals: attempting to hook OatFileManager::HasCollisions
2019-10-01 13:23:34.382 18447-18447/? E/dalvik-internals: attempting to hook OatFileAssistant::IsUpToDate
2019-10-01 13:23:34.383 18447-18447/? E/dalvik-internals: attempting to hook OatFileAssistant::IsUpToDate
2019-10-01 13:23:34.383 18447-18447/? E/dalvik-internals: could not hook _ZN3art16OatFileAssistant17OatFileIsUpToDateEv
2019-10-01 13:23:34.383 18447-18447/? E/dalvik-internals: attempting to hook OatFileAssistant::IsUpToDate
2019-10-01 13:23:34.384 18447-18447/? E/dalvik-internals: could not hook _ZN3art16OatFileAssistant18OdexFileIsUpToDateEv
2019-10-01 13:23:34.384 18447-18447/? E/dalvik-internals: attempting to hook OatFileAssistant::IsUpToDate
2019-10-01 13:23:34.384 18447-18447/? E/dalvik-internals: could not hook _ZN3art16OatFileAssistant22GivenOatFileIsUpToDateERKNS_7OatFileE
2019-10-01 13:23:34.522 18537-18537/? E/dboxed_process: Not starting debugger since process cannot load the jdwp agent.
2019-10-01 13:23:34.625 18447-18447/? E/dalvik-internals: skipping IsUpToDate check for incoming dex file
2019-10-01 13:23:35.099 18447-18591/? E/fb4a.FbTrafficStats: Unable to parse data usage from system file
    X.2LF: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /proc/net/xt_qtaguid/stats (Permission denied)
        at X.16c.A00(:235)
        at X.16X.A04(:32)
        at X.16Y.run(:10)
        at X.0c2.run(:2)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at X.0cA.run(:3)
        at X.0cC.run(:12)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
     Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /proc/net/xt_qtaguid/stats (Permission denied)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:231)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:165)
        at X.16c.A00(:16)
        at X.16X.A04(:32) 
        at X.16Y.run(:10) 
        at X.0c2.run(:2) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) 
        at X.0cA.run(:3) 
        at X.0cC.run(:12) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764) 
2019-10-01 13:23:35.100 18447-18591/? E/fb4a.FbTrafficStats: Unable to parse data usage from system file
    X.2LF: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /proc/net/xt_qtaguid/stats (Permission denied)
        at X.16c.A00(:235)
        at X.16X.A04(:55)
        at X.16Y.run(:10)
        at X.0c2.run(:2)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at X.0cA.run(:3)
        at X.0cC.run(:12)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
     Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /proc/net/xt_qtaguid/stats (Permission denied)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:231)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:165)
        at X.16c.A00(:16)
        at X.16X.A04(:55) 
        at X.16Y.run(:10) 
        at X.0c2.run(:2) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) 
        at X.0cA.run(:3) 
        at X.0cC.run(:12) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764) 
2019-10-01 13:23:35.270 1916-1916/? E/MiuiFaceFactory: getCurrentAuthType sCurrentAuthType = 1
2019-10-01 13:23:35.270 1916-1916/? E/MiuiFaceFactory: getFaceManager sCurrentAuthType = 1
2019-10-01 13:23:35.271 1916-1916/? E/MiuiFaceFactory: getCurrentAuthType sCurrentAuthType = 1
2019-10-01 13:23:35.271 1916-1916/? E/MiuiFaceFactory: getFaceManager sCurrentAuthType = 1
2019-10-01 13:23:35.271 1916-1916/? E/MiuiFaceFactory: getCurrentAuthType sCurrentAuthType = 1
2019-10-01 13:23:35.271 1916-1916/? E/MiuiFaceFactory: getFaceManager sCurrentAuthType = 1
2019-10-01 13:23:35.271 1916-1916/? E/MiuiFaceFactory: getCurrentAuthType sCurrentAuthType = 1
2019-10-01 13:23:35.271 1916-1916/? E/MiuiFaceFactory: getFaceManager sCurrentAuthType = 1
2019-10-01 13:23:35.271 1916-1916/? E/MiuiFaceFactory: getCurrentAuthType sCurrentAuthType = 1
2019-10-01 13:23:35.271 1916-1916/? E/MiuiFaceFactory: getFaceManager sCurrentAuthType = 1
2019-10-01 13:23:35.283 18447-18563/? E/CompactDiskManagerImpl.cpp:697: Failed to remove new folder structure directories: No such file or directory
2019-10-01 13:23:35.949 18447-18532/? E/fb4a.PassiveBleCollector: Couldn't start passive BLE scanning
    X.9Nc: Ble scan error: USER_DISABLED
        at X.9O1.A00(:29)
        at X.9O1.Bbo(:4)
        at X.4ix.A00(:4)
        at X.9Nf.run(:439)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:65)
        at X.0bn.run(:0)
2019-10-01 13:23:36.135 18646-18646/? E/m.facebook.orc: Not starting debugger since process cannot load the jdwp agent.
2019-10-01 13:23:36.160 18660-18660/? E/book.appmanage: Not starting debugger since process cannot load the jdwp agent.
2019-10-01 13:23:36.194 18646-18646/? E/m.facebook.orc: Dex checksum does not match for dex: /system/framework/com.google.android.maps.jar.Expected: 3079070930, actual: 1845989642
2019-10-01 13:23:36.248 18660-18660/? E/ACRA: Initializing ANR detector for process: com.facebook.appmanager
2019-10-01 13:23:36.268 18660-18660/? E/SQLiteLog: (14) cannot open file at line 36667 of [c255889bd9]
2019-10-01 13:23:36.268 18660-18660/? E/SQLiteLog: (14) os_unix.c:36667: (2) open(/data/user/0/com.facebook.appmanager/databases/androidx.work.workdb) - 
2019-10-01 13:23:36.269 18660-18660/? E/SQLiteDatabase: Failed to open database '/data/user/0/com.facebook.appmanager/databases/androidx.work.workdb'.
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14 SQLITE_CANTOPEN): Could not open database
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeOpen(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:211)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:195)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.openConnectionLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:503)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:204)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:196)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openInner(SQLiteDatabase.java:880)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.open(SQLiteDatabase.java:865)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:766)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:714)
        at com.facebook.oxygen.common.androidx.workmanager.initializer.b.a(WorkManagerDatabase.java:20)
        at com.facebook.oxygen.appmanager.app.c.b(AppManagerApplicationImpl.java:19)
        at com.facebook.oxygen.common.f.b.d.onCreate(OxpDelegatingApplication.java:68)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1155)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5948)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:200)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1673)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6809)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:876)
2019-10-01 13:23:36.382 18660-18697/? E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.appmanager.nekodirect
2019-10-01 13:23:36.459 18646-18689/? E/ACRA: Initializing ANR detector for process: com.facebook.orca
```

I have tried with Expo 35 bareApp then also getting same issue.

can anyone help out from this issue. stuck since 2 days.

Comment: if you open logcat and see the error it would be helpful. I remember facing a similar thing but mine was more around the fact that I was not using the latest version of gms

Comment: @Rigorousimplementation updated and tried this one alos https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/25024#issuecomment-495672078

Comment: is this problem of **gms**.which version should i use
```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:10.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.0.1'
```